How do I change a specific character in mutliple file names. The character can be at any location in the file name
OK, I have some files that have a character such as - at different positions in their name. I want to change - to lets say _
Is it possible via a command line
Example of file names
one-test.pdf
test - old.pdf 3-.pdf cat-and-dog.pdf
Many thanks

In your specific case, and assuming that all the files are in the same directory, that would be:
for x in ./*.pdf; do mv "$x" "${x//-/_}"; done

